# MySQL BETWEEN operator with SQL patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I've tried to google the answer, but found nothing, also neither [MySQL BETWEEN page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) nor [MySQL Pattern matching page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) have any information about it.

So, I'm curious, is it correct to use SQL patterns in **BETWEEN** operator, like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01%' AND '2019-02-01%'` in case of `date` pattern is `Y-m-d H:i`.

It is not recommended to use SQL patterns in **=**, **>** and **<** cases, but nothing about **BETWEEN**

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `like` support with `between`.  It just doesn't make sense.

Second, you should not be using *string* functions on dates.  MySQL has lots of really useful string fucntions.

And finally, you can just use regular comparisons:

```
where date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2019-02-02'
```

Ironically, this will work both when the date column is stored (properly) as a `date`.  And also what it is stored as a `datetime`.  And as a string (given the format you specify).

Comment: Exactly, I've wondered about it because of this works with `datetime` fine. So, it's just drops pattern in `BETWEEN` statement?

Comment: @Scilef . . . They are just characters in a string.  And you are forcing type conversions for the comparison.  And it might be affected by internationalization settings on your system.  And it might prevent index usage.  And accessing partitions in a partitioned table.  An all-around bad idea.